# How can I write PHP syntax in a string

Tags: php, heredoc, nowdoc

I tried to write some content in order to write in a php file and in my $content variable i use Heredoc and nowdoc but php tags seems not working and are still shown.

```
$content = <<< EOT
<?php
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/home/index2.php';
?> 
EOT;
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [Output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) instead of a heredoc:

```
ob_start();
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/home/index2.php';
$content = ob_get_clean();
```

Reference:

- [`ob_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)
- [`ob_get_clean()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php)

Comment: bes solution, I knew\use it, just up and comment $)

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$content = "<" . <<< EOT
?php
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/home/index2.php';
> 
EOT;
```